# Which symmetric algorithm should I use for storing files in untrusted servers?

Tags: encryption, aes, symmetric, file-encryption, key-size

I have gigabites of files, which I have to backup. I have some servers for storing this files. But these servers are untrusted. So I need to encrypt files, then backup files. When my PC  breaks down, I will dowload files from unstrucsted servers and restore them.

So, basically, I think about AES-256. Is it OK for me, or there is more suitable symmetric algorithms?

Comment: There is much more you have to worry about than a choice of pseudorandom permutation family, which is what AES-256 is—that's about the least interesting question.  At the very least, start one level up: What _authneticated cipher_ should I use?  Standard answers are NaCl crypto_secretbox_xsalsa20poly1305, AES-GCM, AES-SIV.  (These are all somewhat different: slightly different security contracts.  If you want details on that, ask another question!)  Study the design of Tarsnap or borgbackup if you're interested in actually pursuing this.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note: AES is not a encryption scheme, it is technically just a block cipher; though it is a fine one.

To create a cipher you need to use it in a mode like counter mode.

To obtain chosen ciphetext security (which is the usual aim) you should use an authenticated encryption scheme such as Galois/Counter Mode.

As usual, don't try make it yourself, use a premade secure library.